# filter based output of first cypher query (subquery)

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have following csv.

I had created the nodes and relations as follows:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///invoice.csv" AS row  
CREATE (INVOICE:INVOICE {TRANS_DATE: row.TRANS_DATE,INVOICE_NO: row.INVOICE_NO,ARTICLE_NO: row.ARTICLE_NO,CUSTOMER_NO: row.CUSTOMER_NO,AMT: row.AMT,QTY: row.QTY})
MERGE (ARTICLE:ARTICLE {product_no: row.ARTICLE_NO})
CREATE (INVOICE)-[:contains]->(ARTICLE);
```

Now I can query the invoices whose articles are more than one :

```
match (i:INVOICE) 
 with i.INVOICE_NO as INVOICE_NO, count(*) as INV_CNT
 where INV_CNT > 1 
 return INVOICE_NO,INV_CNT
```

Now I would like to display articles which are contained in above invoices. I tried a lot but didn't succeeded. I would appreciate help from you guys.

## invoice.csv

```
sr_no,TRANS_DATE,TICKET_NO,ARTICLE_NO,CUSTOMER_NO,AMT,QTY
1,20190101,1,1,1,200,1
2,20190101,1,2,1,500,4
3,20190101,2,1,1,20,5
4,20190101,3,4,1,20,6
5,20190101,4,5,4,20,7
6,20190101,4,6,4,20,1
7,20190101,4,1,4,20,2
8,20190101,5,1,9,20,2
9,20190101,6,2,10,20,1
10,20190101,7,8,11,20,1
11,20190101,8,4,21,20,1
12,20190101,8,5,21,20,1
13,20190101,9,1,25,20,1
14,20190101,10,11,50,20,5
15,20190101,11,11,14,20,1
16,20190101,12,12,14,20,1
17,20190101,13,4,10,20,3
18,20190101,14,14,1,20,1
19,20190101,14,14,1,20,2
20,20190101,14,14,1,20,200
```

Comment: Are you getting correct results for "invoices whose articles are more than one" ?

Comment: Yes I am able to get correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your query to get "invoices whose articles are more than one" is correct and adding how you can add the optional match to get the list of articles.

For each Invoice it will optionally match the Article.

```
MATCH (i:INVOICE) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (i)-[:contains]->(a:ARTICLE)
WITH i.INVOICE_NO AS INVOICE_NO, COUNT(*) AS INV_CNT, COLLECT(a) AS articles
WHERE INV_CNT > 1 
RETURN INVOICE_NO, INV_CNT, articles
```

You can simplify it like:

```
MATCH (i:INVOICE)-[:contains]->(a:ARTICLE)
WITH i.INVOICE_NO AS INVOICE_NO, COUNT(*) AS INV_CNT, COLLECT(a) AS articles
WHERE INV_CNT > 1 
RETURN INVOICE_NO, INV_CNT, articles
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. This is what required. Thanks a ton.